# Getting Error as "ValueError: Zip does not support timestamps before 1980" while installing Setuptools-scm Pypi

Tags: python

**Describe the bug**

Am working on a Client machine where I don't have access to external servers. So I have to download the packages from Python websites and extract the zip-files and I have to install the packages in my machine by passing a command `python setup.py install` in command prompt. First two packages (`Selenium` and `urllib3`) working fine in my machine and setup also good.

I have tried to install the `Pytest Pypi` but that requires `setuptools-scm`. So I downloaded the `setuptools-scm` packages and I tried to install it but I am getting an error `ValueError: Zip does not support timestamps before 1980`.

**Expected behavior**

`Setuptools-scm` should be installed

**To Reproduce**

- Download the `setuptools-scm` package from https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/
- Extract the zip-files and installing the `setuptools-scm` by running `python setup.py install`
- Observe the error `ValueError: Zip does not support timestamps before 1980`.

**Command Prompt response**:

```
    File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.8\lib\zipfile.py", line 360, in __init__
        raise ValueError('ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980')
    ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because files had a last modified date on them on 1st of january 1970. I simply touch all the files to update the last modified to today and everything works.

```
$ touch `find . -type f`
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in python3.9. I could resolve it by changing all instance's of `strict_timestamps` from `True` to `False` (i.e. `strict_timestamps=False`) in `zipfile.py` inside `Lib` folder (`..\Python\Python39\Lib\`). [Reference](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9910)

Comment: your answer was top. Where did you get this inspiration? Could you tell us what will be the drawbacks on those changes?

Comment: @CharlesSantos This was one error that I spend a quite lot of time resolving. It was frustrating initially but the lack of proper documentation for encountering this gave me the rush to resolve it :D. I had been using this method for at least a month now, I couldn't see any notable drawbacks for this.

Comment: Although I came across this problem with installing statsmodels, 
Still exactly answer!! After changing all strict_timestamps from True to False, I finally successfully complete installing it!

Comment: Changing the code of libraries isn't good practice (might cause other apps to misbehave). Instead look at what creates the zip file and pass in `strict_timestamps=False` in there.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too. That's because I use "WinRAR" to decompress package( *.tar.gz), so many files don't have dates on them. Then I  use cmd tools and the command `tar -zxvf *.tar.gz` to decompress this package, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the files in src/setuptools_scm/ didn't have a timestamp for date created or modified.  I simply opened the files in a text editor and saved them without changes to establish a timestamp.

After that, >python ./setup.py install worked as expected.